Tacacs+ server with IPv6 on Ubuntu
How to make Tacacs+ server to work with Ipv6 address on Ubuntu?
It works fine with Ipv4 address but authentication fails when using IPv6 tacacs+.

Is your system set up for IPv6? Have you read the tacacs+ documentation ( man pages, info pages, README files, ...)?

You are probably best to stop using tacacs+ and instead use radius.

Yes. The system is set up for IPv6 and netstat -l shows the entries for tacacs for both tcp and tcp6 but still the authentication works fine with IPv4 address and fails for IPv6 address.
